# Float a div without defining height property

Tags: html, css

It looks very simple (and maybe is, just got stucked) -> just for fun, no practical need right now.

**I got this:**

[image]

```
<div class="master">
    <div class="left">
        <p>LEFT</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.master {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.left {
    width:10%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}
.left p {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.right {
    width: 89%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
    color: #FFF;
}
.right p {
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    text-align: justify
}
```

So, as you can see, I didn't define height property, so red div just takes the needed height.

**What I am looking for is something like this:**
The red div takes all height of master, while  blue is staying more *tall*.

[image]

**[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscocarvalho/U3k4m/)**

Comment: You could use a flexbox.

Comment: this is a common and frustrating shortcoming of HTML and (browser-supported-css). There are several hacky solutions, and some new cutting edge CSS3 ones (flexbox).

Comment: A good write-up of a similar problem and sample solutions: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: @ZachL, how is this a shortcoming? There seems to be a pretty straightforward solution to this as described the answers.

Comment: The solutions below force you to set the `display` property of the divs to `table`-(`cell`). I forget exactly how those differ from `block`-level elements, but I remember there being a couple gotchas. I'll look into this now.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps I was remembering when I still had to support IE7/8. CSS-Table properties are [IE8+ Only](http://caniuse.com/css-table) Happy those days are over ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is:

```
.master {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.left {
    width:10%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    display: table;
}
.right {
    width: 89%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
    color: #FFF;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Would it make more sense to use display: table-cell for .left and .right?

Comment: Works like a charm! But, as @marcaudet said, I guess that `table-cell` would make more sense. :) Already tried but didn't work as `table`does

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach that does not use CSS tables is as follows:

```
.master {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    position: relative;
}
.left {
    width:10%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.right {
    width: 89%;
    margin-left: 11%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: blue;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

If the `.right` block is the one that controls the overall height, keep `.right` in regular content flow and set `margin-left: 11%` to leave some white space.

Use absolute position to place and size the `.left` block.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/97CY2/

However, if you don't know which of the two child elements is the taller, than table-cell's would be the way to go.

Comment: Here's an awesome answer! In this case, the taller cild is the `.right` one, so might use 1st way as Michael said. But really god answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `display:table` on the container and `display:table-cell` on the children:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4gDqH/11/)**

CSS:

```
.master {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table;
}
.left {
    background: red;
    display:table-cell;
    width:10%;
}
.left p {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.right {
    border-left: 10px solid #fff;
    background: blue;
    color: #FFF;
    display:table-cell;
}
.right p {
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    text-align: justify
}
```

Comment: You could add `display: table` to `.master` but the CSS engine is smart enough to create an annonymous table around `.left` and `.right`, so either way, this works and you get the advantage of using `vertical-align` is needed.

Comment: @MarcAudet `display:table` got deleted somehow along the process... I just put it back like my first intention