# Keeping Two Stacked Divs Same Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to build my site and in one location I have two divs stacked on top of each other to the right of an image.  The two divs should each be half the height of the image  as long as the browser is over 767px and be responsive as well.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dC7z5/

```
<div class='row subhead'>
  <div class='col-sm-9'>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/900/554" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>

  <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-sm-12 services'>
            <p>Services</p>
              <ul>
                  <li>first service</li>
                  <li>another service</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-sm-12 specs'>
              <p>Tech Specs</p>
              <ul>
                  <li>one spec</li>
                  <li>second spec</li>
              </ul>
          </div> <!-- end specs -->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do: http://laurenpittenger.com/here/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Screen-Shot-2014-01-05-at-4.46.31-PM.png

Comment: You can add height:255px !important; to .specs class

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908877/float-a-div-without-defining-height-property/20909007#20909007

Comment: Must find a Bootstrap solution, it must be out there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div container that contains both the Service box, and the Tech Specs Box. Then, in the css, make the container the same height as the image. Do this to the Service and Tech Specs Box:

```
height:50%;
```