# Make floated links have same height?

Tags: css

Im making a liquid width site. I have 3 links side by side, each taking up 33%.

For smaller screen widths the text wraps, first for the link with the longest text. What I need is for the links to all have the same height.

[image]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HGFeJ

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Some text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Some other longer text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Short</a>
  </li>
</ul>

a {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background: gold;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

From reading other answers on SO I thought id be able to do this with the table and table-cell display CSS properties, but it doesn't seem to work:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/toAIa

Comment: Actually asked this before... [Float a div without defining height property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908877/float-a-div-without-defining-height-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give `table-cell` for `li` not `a` because `a` is nesting inside `li`

**[Working codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/sEueJ)**

Eg:

```
li{
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: To be fair, this doesn't actually make the anchors the same height, just the `li`s.

Comment: @Matt The answer was provided for what OP asked in the screenshot. He did not wanted to increase the height of `<a>`